# Codeigniter - Only allow specific user to edit/delete post

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Im trying to do so that only the author of the post can edit and delete it from the list where it is shown.

this is my **view**:

```
<?php if (($this->session->userdata('logged_in')==TRUE)) { ?>
                <a href="<?php echo site_url("edit/$data[id_post]")?>" type="button">edit</a>
                <a href="<?php echo site_url("delete/$data[id_post]")?>" type="button">delete</a>
                <?php } ?>
```

The above code makes sure that only logged in users can actually edit the post, however they can edit all posts, and not only their own. In my /create i have made a hidden field, so that my posts are saved with the id of the author, so that relationship works just fine. However my question is, how do i make sure that authors only can edit their own posts?

Thanks!

**Update:**

Here is the **Contoller**

```
public function index()
{
    if (($this->session->userdata('id')!=NULL)) 
    {       
    $data['view'] = $this->home_model->list_data();
    $created_by_sql = $this->db->query('SELECT id FROM user JOIN post ON user.id=post.id_user');
    if ($created_by_sql->num_rows() > 0)
    {
      foreach ($created_by_sql ->result() as $row)
      {
         $user_id = $row->id;
      }
    }
    $data["user_id"] = $user_id;
    $this->load->view('home_table',$data);
```

Here is **model**

```
public function list_data()
{   
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('post as p');
    $this->db->join('user as u', 'p.id_user = u.id');
    $this->db->order_by("p.id_post", "desc");
    $query = $this->db->get(); 
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

And this is my **View**

```
<?php foreach($view as $data): ?>
<?php if (!empty($data['source'])) { ?>
     <div class="sumber">anda<?php echo $data['source'];?></div>
<?php } ?>
<?php if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in')==TRUE AND $user_id == $this->session->userdata('id')) { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo site_url("edit/$data[id_post]")?>" type="button">edit</a>
    <a href="<?php echo site_url("delete/$data[id_post]")?>" type="button">delete</a>
    <?php } else { echo 'id user not same with iduser_Login';} ?>`
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: with login check check post author id with user id if they match give edit permission then your condition will be like this if (($this->session->userdata('logged_in')==TRUE && $user_id == $post_author_id))

Comment: i'am trying this one 
Controller:
$data['create_by'] = $this->db->query('SELECT id FROM user JOIN post ON user.id=post.id_user');
$this->load->view('home_table',$data);

View:
<?php if (($create_by == $this->session->userdata('id'))) { ?>
//delete button view

But the delete button not display

Comment: @Andhika Ragil Kesuma please check the update below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, You should put id of user into the session and You should insert one more if clause inside the the first if clause and check whether the authorid of article is equal to id of the user in the session.

**--UPDATE--**

According to the comments above, you should:

Inside the controller:

```
$created_by_sql = $this->db->query('SELECT id FROM user JOIN post ON user.id=post.id_user');
if ($created_by_sql->num_rows() > 0)
{
  foreach ($created_by_sql ->result() as $row)
  {
     $user_id = $row->id;
  }
}

$data["user_id"] = $user_id;

$this->load->view('home_table',$data);
```

Inside the view:

```
if($user_id == $this->session->userdata('id'))
{
  //delete button
}
```

**--UPDATE 2--**

We must reorganize the logic. First, in the controller:

```
//get the posts:
$posts = array();
$sql = $this->db->query("select id AS post_id, title as post_title, id_user as user_id from post"); //please edit query to fit your needs
foreach($sql->result() as $row)
{
  $posts[] = $row; //now, each post row carries user_id of its author.
}

//send data to view:
$data["posts"] = $posts;
$data["current_user_id"] = $this->session->userdata('id');


//load view
$this->load->view('home_table',$data);
```

Inside the view, we should print posts as follow:

```
<?php 
for($i = 0; $i < count($posts); $i++)
{ 
    echo $posts[$i]["post_title"]; echo " | ";

    //compare 
    if($post[$i]["user_id"] == $current_user_id)
    {
        echo "CAN DELETE";
    }
    echo "<br />";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks you answer my question veri quickly :D i am update my question now... I think because of id_user in list_data crash with $id_user

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, it will help :)

**Controller:**

```
//DELETE
function delete($item, $user)
{
    $data['baseurl'] = $this->config->item('base_url');
    $logged_in = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
    $logged_user = $this->session->userdata('logged_user');
    $user= $this->uri->segment(4);
    $item= $this->uri->segment(3);
    if (($logged_in == TRUE) && ($logged_user == $user)) {
        $data['user'] = $user;
        $data['item'] = $item;
        $result = $this->Model->delete($data);
        if(isset($result)) {
            $success_msg = "Deleted";
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success_msg', $success_msg);
        }
        redirect('admin/list');
    }
    else {
        redirect ('login');
    }
}
//EDIT
function edit($item, $user)
{
    $data['baseurl'] = $this->config->item('base_url');
    $logged_in = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
    $logged_user = $this->session->userdata('logged_user');  
    $user= $this->uri->segment(4);
    $item= $this->uri->segment(3);      
    if (($logged_in == TRUE) && ($logged_user == $user)) {
        $data['info'] = $this->input->post('info');
        $data['user'] = $user;
        $data['item'] = $item;
        $update = $this->Model->edit($data);
        redirect ('admin/list);
    }
    else {
        redirect ('login');
    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
//DELETE
function delete($data)
{
    $sql = 'DELETE * FROM info WHERE user_id = '.$data['user'].' AND id = '.$data['item'].' ';
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $this->db->affected_rows();
}
//EDIT
function edit($data)
{
    $condition = array(
           'user' => $data['user'], 
           'item' => $data['item']
    );
    $update = array(
           'info' => $data['info']
    );
    $this->db->where($condition);
    $this->db->update('info', $update);
    return $this->db->affected_rows();
}
```

**View:**

```
<a href="<?php echo $baseurl; ?>/main/delete/<?php echo $item; ?>/<?php echo $user; ?>">DELETE</span></a>
<a href="<?php echo $baseurl; ?>/main/edit/<?php echo $item; ?>/<?php echo $user; ?>">EDIT</span></a>
```